# Multiprocessing in Flask with a function that runs forever

Tags: python, flask

For a school project, I am required to control some LEDs on a Raspberry Pi through C remotely. Using pigpio, I have managed to create the following is code snippet from the shared library file I have created:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pigpio.h>

void initialise_pins(int LED_1, int LED_2){
    gpioInitialise(); /*Initialise the pigpio library*/
    gpioSetMode(LED_1, PI_OUTPUT); /*Set LED to output*/
    gpioSetMode(LED_2, PI_OUTPUT); /*Set LED to output*/
}

int light_status(int GPIOPinNumber){
    return (gpioRead(GPIOPinNumber));
}

void clear_all(int LED_1, int LED_2){
    gpioWrite(LED_1, OFF); /*Resets LED_1 to off*/
    gpioWrite(LED_2, OFF); /*Resets LED_2 to off*/
}

void turn_on_lights(int LED_1, int LED_2){
    gpioWrite(LED_1, ON); /*Turns on LED_1*/
    gpioWrite(LED_2, ON); /*Turns on LED_1*/
}
```

Together with this shared library file, to meet the requirement of controlling it remotely, I have decided to use Flask on python to call the functions from my shared library. The following is the Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from multiprocessing import Process
import ctypes
import multiprocessing
import time

light_functions = ctypes.CDLL('./light_function.so')

LED_1 = 13
LED_2 = 19

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    # Read Sensors Status
    light_functions.initialise_pins(LED_1, LED_2)
    LED_1_Status = 'Off'
    LED_2_Status = 'Off'
    if light_functions.light_status(LED_1):
        LED_1_Status = 'On'
    if light_functions.light_status(LED_2):
        LED_2_Status = 'On'
    templateData = {
        'title': 'GPIO output Status!',
        'LED_1': LED_1_Status,
        'LED_2': LED_2_Status
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)


@app.route('/<action>')
def action(action):
    LED_1_Status = 'Off'
    LED_2_Status = 'Off'
    if action == 'turn_on':
        light_functions .turn_on_lights(LED_1, LED_2)
    if action == 'turn_off':
        light_functions .clear_all(LED_1, LED_2)
    if action == "blink":
        p = Process(target=blink_lights(), args=(), daemon=True)
        p.start()
    if action == "stop_blink":
        kill_blink()
    if light_functions.light_status(LED_1):
        LED_1_Status = 'On'
    if light_functions.light_status(LED_2):
        LED_2_Status = 'On'
    templateData = {
        'title': 'GPIO output Status!',
        'LED_1': LED_1_Status,
        'LED_2': LED_2_Status
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)


def blink_lights():
    while True:
        light_functions.turn_on_lights(LED_1, LED_2)
        time.sleep(1)
        light_functions.clear_all(LED_1, LED_2)
        time.sleep(1)



def kill_blink():
    processes = multiprocessing.active_children()
    for process in processes:
        process.terminate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

The issue I am currently facing is that the function `blink_lights()` cannot be stopped even with `kill_blink()`. The lights will continuously blink even after the kill function has been called and I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Do you only have 1 flask worker? If so, then probably it's busy with the `while True` and can't process the `kill_blink` request.

Comment: The cleanest way to handle cases like this is with Multiprocessing.Event.  `blink_lights` loops while the event is not set.  `kill_blink` sets the event to true.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event

Comment: @FrankYellin Thank you, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code:

```
p = Process(target=blink_lights(), args=(), daemon=True)
```

It starts `blink_lights` loop and can not even return something to assign to `target` parameter. So, obviously you need to remove function call like this:

```
p = Process(target=blink_lights, args=(), daemon=True)
```

But multiprocessing.Event in comments is a good suggestion for the next step (after fixing this bug).